# Smallest lexicographical value of a string

Tags: c++, string, c++11

When comparing strings with operator <, what is the *smallest* string?

To be more specific, what is a string that is smaller (using <) than any other string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The empty string is the "smallest" of all strings - that is, it compares less than any non-empty string.

§21.4.8.4 [string::op<]:

> ```
> template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
> bool operator< (const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
>                 const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 1 *Returns*: `lhs.compare(rhs) < 0`.

§21.4.7.9 [string::compare]:

> ```
> int compare(const basic_string& str) const noexcept;
> ```
>
> 1 *Effects*: Determines the effective length `rlen` of the strings to
>   compare as the smallest of `size()` and `str.size()`. The function
>   then compares the two strings by calling `traits::compare(data(),
>   str.data(), rlen)`.
>
> 2 *Returns*: The nonzero result if the result of the
>   comparison is nonzero. Otherwise, returns a value as indicated in
>   Table 72.
>
> Table 72 — compare() results
>
> ```
>  Condition               Return Value
>  size() < str.size()     < 0
>  size() == str.size()    0
>  size() > str.size()     > 0
> ```

For any comparison between an empty string `e` and a non-empty string `ne`, `rlen` is zero, in which case `traits::compare()` is specified to return zero<sup>*</sup>. Hence, the result of `e.compare(ne)` is always less than zero per table 72, and `e < ne` is always true.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>The `compare()` function of character traits is specified to return zero if "for each i in [0,n), `X::eq(p[i],q[i])` is true" (§21.2.1 [char.traits.require], Table 62); when `n == 0`, the range is empty, and the condition is vacuously true.</sub>

Comment: tldr; since `"AB"` is less than `"ABX"`, in the same way `""` is less than `"X"` or any other string of length 1