# What is the lexicographically smallest string in Python?

Tags: python

What is the lexicographically smallest string in Python? In other words, what is the string `x` such that `x < y` is always `True` (where `y` is a string)?

For example, in C++ the *empty string* is the smallest one (see [Smallest lexicographical value of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344045/smallest-lexicographical-value-of-a-string)). Can anyone confirm that the same answer holds for Python?

This is what I've tried so far:

```py
import string

for x in list(string.printable):
    assert("" < x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `x` as empty string, `x < y` for any string `y` holds `True` in Python.

We can confirm this:

```
>>> all('' < x for x in string.printable)
True
```

[`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) returns a `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). The less than (`<`) operation of empty string with all string printables is thus a `True`.

This is true for non-printable characters as well.
The total range vary from 0 to 1,1141,111(0x10FFFF in base 16) (thanks to @AlexHall in comments).

```
>>> all('' < chr(i) for i in range(0x110000))
True
```

Comment: I have already tried to check the printable characters, as you can see in my question. What about non-printable characters?

Comment: The empty string is smaller than any string with a character in it, whether printable or not.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you for your answer. Is there any proof?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco `all('' < chr(i) for i in range(0x110000))`

Comment: The non-printing character `"\0x00"` is smaller than any character with a higher codepoint. And `""  < "\0x00"` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexHall, I think the answer you gave in your comment should be accepted.

Comment: @AlexHall, please add this as an answer, so I could remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is the smallest string you can get, since its length is 0 (that's also the string returned by `str()`)

However, I did not find anything in the documentation to explicitly confirm that...

> https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons
>   https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__